# Date and Time in UTC and local format in Magento

Tags: date, magento, magento-1.9

I display date and time in Magento page. Time displayed is from server (I guess) and I need my local time with (UTC +4:00) I used the below code (thanks for suport) :

```
<div class="header-right"><div class="clear"></div>         
<div style="text-align: right;" class="date-time">
    <?php echo strftime('%c');?>
</div>
```

Any support will be highly apreciated.

**Site: [www.ozams.com](http://www.ozams.com)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only server time because of problems with local time. If your local time is wrong, so wrong date will be displayed.
I hope next links will help you in formatting:
[Magento: Date format troubles](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-date-format/)
[Playing with dates in magento](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/)
[Guide through Magento’s timezones](http://inchoo.net/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/)
I guess your problem is in your settings

Answer (score 0):

To render local time in `.phtml` file, try

```html
    <?php // Render local date and time ?>
    <?php echo $this->formatDate(null, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, true); ?>
    <?php // Render local date ?>
    <?php echo $this->formatDate(); ?>
```